# Calling groupBy method from dataset object through java interop using clojure

Tags: java, apache-spark, clojure, interop

I need to call the `groupBy` method on a `spark dataset` by way of the java interop through clojure.

I only need to call this for one column, but the only groupBy signatures I can get to work involve multiple column names.  The api seems to indicate that I should be able to use only one column name, but I cannot get this to work.  What I really need is a good example to work from.  What am I missing?

This does not work . . .

```
(-> a-dataset

(.groupBy "a-column")
```

This does . . .

```
(-> b-dataset

(.groupBy "b-column", (into-array ["c-column"])
```

The error message I receive says there is `no groupBy method for dataset`.

I know it is looking for a Column, but I don't know how to give it one.

Comment: Thank you for your response! - I wound up wrapping the call in a clojure function that included the dataset in the arguments.  Using that I was able to use the dataset name as a parameter in each of the calls to spark api elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a thing about Spark but think we can understand it better by looking at this example from the [Spark API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) into Clojure:

```java
   // To create Dataset<Row> using SparkSession
   Dataset<Row> people = spark.read().parquet("...");
   Dataset<Row> department = spark.read().parquet("...");

   people.filter(people.col("age").gt(30))
     .join(department, people.col("deptId").equalTo(department.col("id")))
     .groupBy(department.col("name"), people.col("gender"))
     .agg(avg(people.col("salary")), max(people.col("age")));
```

We can assume that you already have a `DataSet` and you want to call `.groupBy` on it. The method that you are probably calling is [the one that takes `Column...` as an argument](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupBy-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-). You were in the right path in that *variadic* argument methods in Java collect the arguments as array, so this is just like receiving a `Column[]` as argument.

The problem is then, how to get a `Column` from a DataSet? It seems you can call [`dataset.col(String colName)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#col-java.lang.String-) to get it. Putting everything together:

```
(.groupBy my-dataset (into-array Column [(.col my-dataset "a-column")]))
```

Again, I don't have how to verify this, but I think this should help.